# Three.js light is not static

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I need to create static light (invariant to move of camera) and i need to get actual position of light in fragment shader.

What i am doing now :

```
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, canvas.width() / canvas.height(), 1, 10000);
        camera.position.z = 2000;
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

        var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
        light.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.1).normalize();
        camera.add(light);

        ....

        var lambertShader = THREE.ShaderLib['lambert'];
        uniformsVolume = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(lambertShader.uniforms);

        ....

        materialVolumeRendering = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: uniformsVolume,
            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
            vertexShader: vertVolumeRendering,
            fragmentShader: fragVolumeRendering,
            vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
            lights :true
        });

        ....
        scene.add(camera);
```

Than in fragment shader i set uniform variable:

```
uniform vec3 spotLightPosition;
```

and compute light for voxel:

```
float dProd = max(0.0, dot(getGradient(posInCube), normalize(lightPos
- posInCube)));             
voxelColored.rgb = voxelColored.rgb * dProd + voxelColored.rgb * 0.2;
```

Problem is, that it doesnt work correctly. My idea is, that i will moving with object (in reality with camera). Light will shine still from the same side (will be static in scene). At this time light is not static and work very strange.

Any idea?
Somebody please...

Tanks a lot.
Tomáš

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `PointLight` instead. `SpotLight` is a bit trickier to use.

Comment: I tried PointLight; it is better but not good.
I am doing now this:

    float dProd = max(0.0,dot(getGradient(posInCube), normalize(normalize(pointLightPosition) - normalize(posInCube)));
 voxelColored.rgb = voxelColored.rgb * dProd + voxelColored.rgb * 0.2;

Comment: I am noob... i found solution. Voxel positions in cube werent in world space :-[ ou... :(

Answer (score 0):

To make your light static in position, then don't add it to your camera, but instead add it to the scene:

scene.add(light);

To find the position reference the variable you used for the light.

light.position

Comment: I think, i have described my problem bad. I need static position in camera space. Ideal example -> camera is flashlight. Light position is same like cameraposition. But it doesnt work.. :(